# Argument of type "BYTE*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR" on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to make a randomly named file on the desktop by getting the desktop path and then combining it with the buffer of `BCryptGetRandom` but the function `PathCombineW` doesn't accept the buffer

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    BYTE Buffer[15];
    DWORD size = sizeof(Buffer);
    BCryptGenRandom(NULL, Buffer, size, BCRYPT_USE_SYSTEM_PREFERRED_RNG);

    LPWSTR desktop;
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &desktop);

    WCHAR filePath[MAX_PATH];
    PathCombineW(filePath, desktop, Buffer); //the error is here
    CreateFileW(filePath, GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Ultimately wide characters are bytes, but the same can be said of any object. Casting might not be enough. Casting to bytes is always safe. Casting from bytes violates strict aliasing unless you've taken extra steps. For example, there could be alignment issues.

Comment: You have not yet decided on a way to convert 15 random bytes into a null-terminated array of `wchar_t` containing only the characters that are allowed for a Windows path.  There's a big step missing from your code.  You also haven't [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: "*I'm trying to make a randomly named file*" - why not use `GetTempFileName()` for that? Or a GUID?

Comment: *I'm trying to make a randomly named file* -- Your question is the classic example of the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  As pointed out, random file names can be generated by getting a [GUID](http://guid.one/guid) and possibly tacking onto it a file extension.

Answer (score 0):

`WCHAR` on Windows is UTF-16LE and you therefore should not use random bytes directly because not everything is going to be valid UTF-16.

You can use a `WCHAR Buffer[15] = {};` and fill 0-13 with numbers in a known valid range, for example from 0x20 to 0xD7FF (excluding things that are [invalid in filenames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)).

If you want to interoperate with non-Unicode programs you might want to limit yourself to ASCII...

Answer (score 0):

A byte array is not a valid null-terminated UTF16 string, which is why `PathCombineW()` won't accept it.

Also, random bytes are not guaranteed to represent valid UTF16 characters.

What you can do is hex-encode the generated bytes into an ASCII string in UTF16 encoding, eg:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    BYTE Buffer[15];
    BCryptGenRandom(NULL, Buffer, sizeof(Buffer), BCRYPT_USE_SYSTEM_PREFERRED_RNG);

    LPWSTR desktop = NULL;
    SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, NULL, &desktop);

    WCHAR fileName[(sizeof(Buffer)*2)+1];
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < sizeof(Buffer); ++i, j += 2) {
        wsprintfW(&fileName[j], L"02X", Buffer[i]);
    }

    WCHAR filePath[MAX_PATH];
    PathCombineW(filePath, desktop, fileName);

    CoTaskMemFree(desktop);

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(filePath, GENERIC_ALL, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```